# Conversion operator in direct-initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

The C++14 standard ([N4296](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/master/papers/n4296.pdf)) says in 8.5/17.6.1

> If the initialization is direct-initialization [...], constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated, and the best
>   one is chosen through overload resolution. [...] If no constructor
>   applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

Therefore in direct-initialization, only constructors are considered - conversion functions are ignored. In the following code there is no applicable constructor of `A`, only a conversion function from `B`. However, the code compiles, why?

```cpp
struct A{};
struct B{
    operator A(){ return A{}; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(b);  // direct-initialization
}
```

Comment: Part of *chosen through overload resolution* is applying conversions.  I'll try and find the applicable section.

Comment: Please explain why you believe it should not find a copy constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that only the constructors of `A` are considered when doing `A a(b);`.  [[over.match.ctor]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.ctor#1) states

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized, copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type ([dcl.init]), or default-initialized, overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization or default-initialization that is not in the context of copy-initialization, **the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized.** For copy-initialization (including default initialization in the context of copy-initialization), the candidate functions are all the converting constructors ([class.conv.ctor]) of that class. The argument list is the expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

This means that `A()`, `A(const A&)` and `A(A&&)` are the candidate list.  Then we have [[over.match.viable]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.viable#4)

> [...]Third, for F to be a viable function, there shall exist for each argument an implicit conversion sequence that converts that argument to the corresponding parameter of F.[..]

which allows an implicit conversion of `b` to an `A` so that `A(A&&)` can be called.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I have removed my answer as this is the right paragraph

Comment: Wouldn't the move-constructor also be considered (and preferred) because `B` can be converted to a prvalue `A`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yep.  Forgot about the move constructor.  Answer updated.